# Opera Out Of memory error with Canvas / kinetic

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a script which I have built using requestAnimationFrmae.

[Code on pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/qbACkxS3)

In chrome it works beautifully. Smooth and perfect. 
However in FF, Opera and Safari its teribbly jerky.

I have a statement which works out if the browser can handle requestAnimationFrame and if it can't resorts back to timeOut()

Can anyone tell me / see why this is so poor / Jerky. And how I can improve the performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  setTimeout(function(){

       requestAnimationFrame(Animate);

       },1000/16.5);
```

seems just wrong to me. It should be just

```
  requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
```

and it should be placed in `Animate`, instead of in `runAnimation` which is reapeatedly called during one animation frame (`Animate` invocation). Btw, the `requestAnimationFrame` shim with `setTimeout` has a very ambitious framerate of 105 fps, 60 should be enough.